# Difference between ::: and ++

Tags: list, scala, collections

For a scala list, what is the difference between

```
:::
```

and

```
++
```

From [doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List)

```
:::  Adds an element at the beginning of this list.
++  Returns a new list containing the elements from the left hand operand followed by the elements from the right hand operand.
```

Comment: Use symbolhound to perform [searches against such cryptic symbols](http://symbolhound.com/?q=%3A%3A%3A+%2B%2B)

Answer (score 1):

`:::`  concatenate two lists eg. `list1 ::: list2`

`++`   concatenate *any two collections* eg. `list1 ++ list2`. Note available only from scala 2.8.